# How to serialize an Intent instance?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to save an Intent instance, returned by `onActivityResult()` after requesting MediaProjection permission. Currently I'm saving it as a static variable to let my app use MediaProjection as many times as needed without requesting it once again. Obviously, this idea fails, when an application gets closed. So I'm looking for a way to serialize intent and use it forever. Are there any ways to serialize or somehow save Intent, which is not Serializable?

Comment: Intent implements `Parcelable`, which is the preferred way of storing things in Android. To save the `Intent` you can use `SharedPreferences` which are able to store objects implementing `Parcelable`.

Comment: Sure, I know, but in this case I need to be able to restore full copy of the object. Seems, Parcelable doesn't give me such opportunities.

Comment: What do you mean by "restore a full copy" which you claim doesn't work? Please explain.

Comment: I need to be able to use the same Intent instance between different app launches. There are two ideas: 
1) Serialize object
2) Save as SharedPreferences
I cannot serialize Intent, because it is not serializable. And I cannot Parcelize it as well, because it contains Binder-objects. And it also can't be stored as SharedPreferency.